# MsTest - get list of tests in AssemblyInitialize

Tags: c#, .net, mstest, vstest

I want to know what tests are going to be executed in the current session with vstest, because there are resources that we initialize in AssemblyInitialize that might not need to be if the tests aren't selected.

This can be affected by the commandline arguments - `VSTest.Console.exe /Tests:` for example.

We’ve tried to do it manually and read the passed args (after using VS 2019 —> Right click —> Run test) using this code:

```cs
[AssemblyInitialize]
public static void AssemblyInitialize(TestContext context)
{
    var args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
}
```

But the args is showing it is executing testhost.exe instead.

So the question is, is there a proper way to get the running tests, and if not, is there a way to get the arguments to parse for ourselves?

Comment: Why is this relevant to you? Just to safe some time during development? If you run the tests in an continuous integration, you'd want to run them all, anyway.

Comment: Exactly to save time, since the full suite takes a very long time to run and during development you only want to run 1-2 tests.

Comment: I actually never used AssemblyInitalize for anything. Either I used the Constructor (to initialize data for every test) or then an initializer fixture, which only runs for the test classes I need them. The tests should decide themselves what they need.